# Trouble with Triggers @DBMS

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi I have been asked to create a Trigger that increments a variable @count on each Insertion.
I have written this query

```
DELIMITER//  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @count int[DEFAULT NULL]    
CREATE TRIGGER trig  
AFTER INSERT ON students  
FOR EACH ROW SET @count = @count + 1;  
END//
```

Now at this point I get the error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax and so on....

In my opinion maybe there is some problem in the declare statement but that is the prescribed syntax on net.

I am using MySQL 5.6 Command Line

Comment: you forget to end delimiter ;

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct and its not mysql way of declare, it should be as below and you do not need to declare the session variables like you did

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trig AFTER INSERT ON student
for each row 
begin
 set @count = @count + 1 ; 
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: No dude , I tried this too , but it gives the same Error. :(